# How to check if a file has been modified outside the program?

Tags: java, file, io, sha1, md5sum

I'm writing a basic version control system using Java, and I'd like to know how I can check for file changes outside my program. I've currently worked out that I should generate SHA-1 or MD5 Hashes for the file and then compare them, but I have no idea how to save the SHA-1 so that I can compare it next time I run the program.

The program works as follows;

```
java myProgram add FILENAME (only works if file has changed. Otherwise does nothing)
```

Comment: Just write the MD5 value into a file.  How and where you do that will depend on how you want to manage it

Comment: Keep it in a database? A property file? Anything that stores data?

Answer (score 0):

You can persist the MD5 Hashes of your file, and later, check if have some difference.

To persist some memory in your program (in a way that you can reboot your machine without lost), you can use several techniques, and the best one depends on how you want to use this memory later. 
Some choices and how to implement:

- Store in some txt File -> You can use [Java I/O](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/package-summary.html) -> [example](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/)
- Store in Data Base -> You can use [Java JDBC API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/jdbc/) -> [example](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/MySQLJava/article.html)
- Serialize an object that represents the data -> [Java

  Serialization](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jndi/objects/serial.html) -> [example](http://www.journaldev.com/2452/java-serialization-example-tutorial-serializable-serialversionuid)